# How to encrypt a SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encryption

Hello I am still kinda new to the Android scene and I am currently hitting a wall. I am making an app to hold all my online accounts and passwords, just something simple, and I want to encrypt the database. I am currently trying to work with SQLCipher and started reading https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/ but for whatever reason I can't get it to implement correctly.

I have the .jar in and the .so's, I did add the .jar file to the library. but the "import info.guardianproject.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;" statement doesn't work.

I also have been at this app for hours now and am getting burned out, might be half the battle.

```
import info.guardianproject.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class PasswordDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static String TABLE;

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_WEBSITE  = "website";
public static final String COLUMN_ACCOUNT = "account";
public static final String COLUMN_PASS = "password";



public PasswordDatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name + ".db", factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    TABLE = name;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_WEBSITE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ACCOUNT + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                      int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean checkAccount(String website, String account) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_WEBSITE + " = \"" + website + "\"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    boolean flag = false;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getString(1).equals(website) && cursor.getString(2).equals(account))
            flag = true;
    } else {
        flag = false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return flag;
}

public void addAccount(String website, String account, String pass) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE, website);
    values.put(COLUMN_ACCOUNT, account);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, pass);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public String lookupAccount(String website, String account) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_WEBSITE + " = \"" + website + "\"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String info = "";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getString(2).equals(account)) {
            info += website + " Account: " + account + " Password: " + cursor.getString(3) + "\n";
            cursor.close();
        }
        else{
            info = null;
        }
    }
    else {
        info = null;
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return info;
}

public boolean removeAccount(String website, String account) {

    boolean result = false;

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_WEBSITE + " = \"" + website + "\"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        if(cursor.getString(2).equals(account)) {
            db.delete(TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)))});
            cursor.close();
            result = true;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}

public boolean updateAccount(String website, String account, String pass) {

    String clCommand = "Select * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_WEBSITE + " = \"" + website + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase dataWriter = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor =  dataWriter.rawQuery(clCommand, null);

    boolean updateOK = false;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE, website);
        values.put(COLUMN_ACCOUNT, account);
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, pass);

        dataWriter.update(TABLE, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))) });
        updateOK = true;
    } else {
        updateOK = false;
    }
    dataWriter.close();
    cursor.close();
    return updateOK;

}

}
```

This is a class I made to handle everything to do with the database not an activity.

Edit**

There is a login to this app with a pin number, that pin number is what I was going to use to decrypt. If this pin is forgotten you can email it to the login email.

Comment: Not sure this is going to be worth the effort.  Where are you going to keep the decryption key?  An attacker could just decompile your app and get the key.  Obfuscation could make it more difficult, but not impossible.  If you keep the key in a web service, you'll need to store the authentication credentials in the app, so that just adds a step.  If the attacker you're trying to guard against is the user, I would give it up.  If it's a malicious app, I would just rely on system security to protect the database file from access by another app.

Comment: Guess I should of went over that, there is a login to this app with a pin number, that pin number is what i was going to use to decrypt. If this pin is forgotten you can email it to the login email.

Comment: So the user enters the PIN every time to decrypt and it isn't saved?  That sounds reasonable.  However I have never done encryption on Android so I don't think I can help you there, sorry.  But your question doesn't really indicate what the problem is.  What is it exactly that isn't working, and how?

Comment: Well the problem is trying to implement the encryption. I can't seem to get the libraries to work. The ones i added in, since the encryption through the java SQLite apparently requires license of some sort. atleast thats what I read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about AES128?

```
package com.test.util;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AesUtil {

    public static String key = "0000000000000090";

    /**
     * hex to byte[] : 16dd
     * @param hex    hex string
     * @return
     */
    public static byte[] hexToByteArray(String hex) {
        if (hex == null || hex.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] ba = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
            ba[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16);
        }
        return ba;
    }

    /**
     * byte[] to hex : unsigned byte
     *
     * @param ba        byte[]
     * @return
     */
    public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] ba) {
        if (ba == null || ba.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(ba.length * 2);
        String hexNumber;
        for (int x = 0; x < ba.length; x++) {
            hexNumber = "0" + Integer.toHexString(0xff & ba[x]);

            sb.append(hexNumber.substring(hexNumber.length() - 2));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * AES 
     *
     * @param message
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
        //KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        //kgen.init(128);
        // use key coss2
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

        // Instantiate the cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        return byteArrayToHex(encrypted);
    }

    /**
     * AES 
     *
     * @param message
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
        //KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        //kgen.init(128);
        // use key coss2
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(hexToByteArray(encrypted));
        String originalString = new String(original);
        return originalString;
    }
}
```

Comment: So in my case I would use this class to encrypt the strings I am putting into my database before entering them?

Comment: Thank you very much! Because I used this method of encrypting the data instead of the database I was able to consolidate down to one database instead of one per user! Thanks again